# vtd-xml evalXPathToString strange behavoir/not working

Tags: java, xml, xpath, vtd-xml

In the second example below, why does `evalXPathToString` print `junk1.45` rather than just `1.45`?

I am using version 2.12 of vtd-xml.

```
String xml = "<xmlDoc><noele>junk</noele><valss>1.45</valss></xmlDoc>";

VTDGen vtdGen = new VTDGen();
vtdGen.setDoc(xml.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
vtdGen.parse(true);
VTDNav vtdNav = vtdGen.getNav();

AutoPilot autoPilot = new AutoPilot(vtdNav);
autoPilot.selectXPath("/xmlDoc/valss");
System.out.println(autoPilot.evalXPathToNumber()); // prints 1.45

autoPilot = new AutoPilot(vtdNav);
autoPilot.selectXPath("/xmlDoc/valss");
System.out.println(autoPilot.evalXPathToString()); // prints junk1.45
```

Comment: https://ximpleware.wordpress.com/2015/10/12/performance-tuning/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried this on  the latest build... and both return 1.45...

This appears to be one of the bugs that has been introduced  in 2.12 and subsequently reported and fixed. The reason it is introduced is because 2.12 aims to fully support mix-content type of XPath evaluation... that is, if you eval xpath "/xmlDoc" to a string, it returns junk1.45..

Also, this bug only concerns evalXPathToString...not other three evaluation methods... I believe /xmlDoc/valss/text() will be one workaround...

If you don't want to wait for the formal release of 2.13 to amend this issue.. you can download the file and build a jar yourself with the following steps...

1. get the patch... go to vtd-xml's cvs host site... 
   http://vtd-xml.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/vtd-xml/ximple-dev/com/ximpleware/LocationPathExpr.java
2. drop the file under com.ximpleware
3. run the build.bat on windows... or whatever is equivalent on your unix machine
4. get the new jar file and replace the old 2.12 jar in the classpath...

Let me know if it works for you or not...

Comment: I haven't built the jar (I use Maven so its a significant amount of work), I've just added that class into my project and it appears to work. Do you know when 2.13 will be available in Maven? Whilst you are here, do you know where I can find information on which objects I should be reusing when working in an xpath heavy application?